# How to generate <ds:DigestValue> and <ds:SignatureValue> using java SAML2.0

Tags: java, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am trying to secure my Java web application using Keycloak SAML authentication but somehow when I am trying to generate the AuthnRequest it is not passing `<ds:DigestValue>` and `<ds:SignatureValue>` and may be because of the keycloak is giving below error:

```
2023-10-24 09:08:03,777 ERROR [org.keycloak.protocol.saml.SamlService] (executor-thread-21) request validation failed: org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: SigAlg was null
```

To generate AuthnRequest my code is as below:

```
 public AuthnRequest buildRequest(String spProviderId, String acsUrl, String idpUrl) {
            
            IssuerBuilder issuerBuilder = new IssuerBuilder();
            Issuer issuer = issuerBuilder.buildObject("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion", "Issuer", "saml2");
            issuer.setValue(spProviderId);

            /* Creation of AuthRequestObject */
            DateTime issueInstant = new DateTime();
            AuthnRequestBuilder authRequestBuilder = new AuthnRequestBuilder();

            AuthnRequest authRequest = authRequestBuilder.buildObject(SAMLConstants.SAML20P_NS, "AuthnRequest", "saml2");
            authRequest.setForceAuthn(false);
            authRequest.setIssueInstant(issueInstant);
            authRequest.setProtocolBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI);
            authRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(acsUrl);
            authRequest.setIssuer(issuer);
            authRequest.setID(generateID());
            authRequest.setVersion(SAMLVersion.VERSION_20);
            authRequest.setDestination(idpUrl);
            authRequest.setNameIDPolicy(buildNameIdPolicy());
            
            XMLObjectBuilder<Signature> signFactory = Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
            Signature signature = signFactory.buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
            Credential cred = null;
                    try {
                        cred = this.getSenderSigningCredential();
                        //signature.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
                        //  signature.setCanonicalizationAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
                          
                        signature.setSigningCredential(cred);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    // Perform signing
                    try {
                          SecurityHelper.prepareSignatureParams(signature, cred, null, null);
                          SecurityConfiguration secConfiguration = Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration(); 
                          NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager namedKeyInfoGeneratorManager = secConfiguration.getKeyInfoGeneratorManager(); 
                          KeyInfoGeneratorManager keyInfoGeneratorManager = namedKeyInfoGeneratorManager.getDefaultManager();
                          KeyInfoGeneratorFactory keyInfoGeneratorFactory = keyInfoGeneratorManager.getFactory(cred);
                          KeyInfoGenerator keyInfoGenerator = keyInfoGeneratorFactory.newInstance();
                          KeyInfo keyInfo = null;
                          try {
                              keyInfo = keyInfoGenerator.generate(cred);
                          } catch  (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          } 
                          signature.setKeyInfo(keyInfo);
                          authRequest.setSignature(signature);
                          
                          
                          
                          Marshaller marshaller = Configuration.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(authRequest);
                          marshaller.marshall(authRequest);
                      
                          
                        Signer.signObject(signature);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            return authRequest;
        }
```

But when I am printing it XML it is showing as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:AuthnRequest 
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:9222/saml/*" Destination="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml" ForceAuthn="false" ID="_4479bf8ac628da22c598a8427556a2ef5be431e5" IssueInstant="2023-10-23T16:26:45.682Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0"><saml2p:Issuer xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">Sample</saml2p:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#_4479bf8ac628da22c598a8427556a2ef5be431e5" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:Transforms xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIICmzCCAYMCBgGK23vMZzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADARMQ8wDQYDVQQDDAZTYW1wbGUwHhcNMjMw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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"/></saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

How can I set those two values, or why keycloak is giving that error?